# Why isn't Tradier's session request working?

Tags: javascript, post, tradier

I am trying to create a small stock simulator with the help of Tradier's API. I wanted to use the streaming service and the first step according to [the docs](https://developer.tradier.com/documentation/markets/create-events-session) is to create a session. I did

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer {my token}" https://api.tradier.com/v1/markets/events/session
```

I took it right from the docs, with my access token, but it keeps giving me

```
{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Invalid API call as no apiproduct match found",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "keymanagement.service.InvalidAPICallAsNoApiProductMatchFound"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the call format, or are the docs wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you've signed up through our developer sandbox. We don't currently support streaming via this product, so while you are able to obtain a session ID through the sandbox, the streaming endpoint is not enabled. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You should open a brokerage account with them and then email customer service to get a API key.  They are very helpful and it won't be much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just change baseurl api to sandbox and add expiration details
like this `https://sandbox.tradier.com/v1/markets/options/strikes?symbol=msft&expiration=2013-06-07`